# Cryptocurrency API with Dates?

Tags: python, json, api, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to analyze cryptocurrency with Python but I can't find any historical data that has dates with them. The closest I have is https://coinmarketcap.com/api/ but there is only ['price_btc', 'market_cap_by_available_supply', 'volume_usd', 'price_usd']) as keys

Does anybody know how I could use Python to get this historical data(timestamped).

Answer (score 0):

You could extract and transform some historical data from coinmarketcap web page.

For example https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/ has tabular data for Bitcoin keyed by `date`, `open`, `high`, `low`, `close`, `volume` and `market cap`.